# PWA standalone issue while redirection in ios 11.3

Tags: web-applications, safari, ios11, progressive-web-apps, ios11.3

When redirecting PWA app to another site(which is login page of our site)opens in safari browser not in standalone mode in ios11.3.(We are using parent.href in javascript to redirect to another site for authentication. This is working fine for older IOS versions).Please help

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue, could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 12.2 was just released 2 days agao and it fixed the problem:

PWAs (Progressive Web App) have a new lifecycle and on most normal situations, the state of your app will be saved and restored between sessions.

A link to an external site opens in a “PWA In-App browser” instead of Safari and if the external site links to the PWA’s scope again, the navigation goes back to the PWA. Now we can log in users on external origins within a PWA (such as with OAuth). Check out [Medium](https://medium.com/@firt/whats-new-on-ios-12-2-for-progressive-web-apps-75c348f8e945) for details.